# why xcodebuild need set specify scheme when build with xcworkspace?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

and in non-workspace building , xcodebuild can build without set any specific scheme?

```
xcodebuild -target dailybuildipa -configuration Debug -sdk iphoneos12.2
```

what does the difference that schemes do between project-building and  workspace-building?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workspace does not contain any scheme by default while xcodeproj does. When you build either through xcodeproj or workspace, you actually build a target under the selected scheme.

**Xcode project**: to work on a single project and its dependencies.

**Workspace**: to work on a group of projects and their dependencies.

Following link will clarify the difference:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Workspace.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009328-CH7-DontLinkElementID_1
*

> "xcodebuild: error: If you specify a workspace then you must also
> specify a scheme"

This error is thrown because, the workspace does not have any idea about the scheme you wish to build. On the other hand every project has a default scheme created with it.
Therefore, `xcodebuild -project *yourProject.xcproj*` will trigger the default scheme or the active one(in the case of multiple schemes)

Read about scheme here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Schemes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009328-CH8-SW1

Choosing a Scheme to Build Your App - https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/BuildingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH53-SW1

Comment: thanks @singhabhi13 , now i got it , and i think the Release is the default configuration ,not the default scheme?

Comment: @ximmyxiao I came across this answer of mine after quite a while and found it does not clarify. Release is not a scheme, it's a configuration. I have edited my answer and provided ref to the documentation. I hope this would clarifies your understanding of xcodeproject, workspace and Scheme